# What is the best way to initialize Ace Editor on an element that does not have an ID?

Tags: angularjs, ace-editor

I've an angularjs app where I want to initialize Ace Editor on an element which does not have an ID attribute.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-ace ? It works well for me, and never requires an id.

Comment: Yes, it works fine if I assign an ID to the div and call the ace on that ID but how can I do that if there's no ID attribute?
Should I assign a random ID just for the sake of calling Ace?

Comment: When you use that angular module, you never "call ace". The directive does it all for you. The examples on that page have no ids.

Comment: Hi Olivia, I tried both approach when I use ui-ace directive, I have an issue with dynamically inserting text in the editor.

I have created another question for that on SO. When I try to use the ace plugin myself without ui-ace directive, I can't even initialize the ace editor.

Comment: Here's another question regarding adding dynamic content in ace editor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885203/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-dynamic-content-to-an-ace-editor-using-ui-ace-direct

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the element to ace.edit function instead of id.